# Does Text Direction get set on Exchange.EmailMessage via Culture?

Tags: c#, exchange-server-2010

I am looking to find out if text direction on an Exchange Email Message is set via the culture property. I know that when I run a right to left check with the below code the cultureInfo shows me that this should be right to left.

```csh
CultureInfo x = new CultureInfo("ar-OM");
Console.WriteLine(x.TextInfo.IsRightToLeft);
Console.Read();
```

When I run a test and check my email I am not seeing the right to left.

```csh
var srvc = new ExchangeService(ExchangeVersion.Exchange2010_SP2);
srvc.Url = new Uri("https://XXXXX.com/EWS/Exchange.asmx");
srvc.UseDefaultCredentials = true;
srvc.TraceEnabled = true;
var msg = new EmailMessage(srvc)
{
    From = new EmailAddress("XXXX@XXXXXX.com")
};
msg.ToRecipients.Add(new EmailAddress("XXXXXXX@gmail.com"));
msg.Subject = "قواعد مراهنات سباقات الخيل";
msg.Body = "إذا كانت لديك أي أسئلة حول بيان الخصوصية هذا أو هذا الاستبيان، يرجى الاتصال بـ";
msg.Culture = "ar-OM";          
msg.Send();
```

Is this because of a setting on my local machine/browser/outlook, or is there something else I need to be doing to get the right to left text direction? I would like to avoid HTML Encoding at this time if possible.